# Jquery ajax() function won't load PHP script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to create a simple login with PHP and MySQL and I'm using the AJAX() jquery function to load the PHP script.
All that I want to do is to load a new web page (for example java2s.com) when the script finds the user in my database.
Problem is that the script won't work at all.
This is the HTML with the Jquery:

EDIT: This is the fixed code thanks to all those who commented, which sadly still doesn't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title> Login </title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript">
function change()
{
document.location.href="http://www.java2s.com";
}

$(document).ready(
$("#loginForm").click(function() {
var jsonlogin=new Object();
jsonlogin.username=$('#username').val();
jsonlogin.password=$('#password').val();
var sendstr = JSON.stringify(jsonlogin);
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'login.php',
        async: false,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: sendstr,
        success:function(response){
        if (response['result']=="login successful")
            {
            change();
            }
        }
    });

    })
  )
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1> INSERT USERNAME AND PASSWORD</h1>
<input type="text" id="username" name="username"> USERNAME <br>
<input type="password" id="password" name="password"> PASSWORD <br>
<input type="submit" id="loginForm" class="button positive">
</body>
</html>
```

The PHP script is very simple:

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$result = json_decode($data);
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","****","*****","*******");
$str="SELECT ID FROM users WHERE username='".$result->username."' AND password='".$result->password."';";
$exists = mysqli_query($con,$str);
if (mysqli_num_rows($exists) ==1)
{
    $arr = array('result'=>"login successful");
    $ris=json_encode($arr);
    echo $ris;
}
else
{
    $arr= array('result'=>"login error");
    $ris=json_encode($arr);
    echo $ris;
}
mysqli_close($con)
?>
```

When I load the page and press the submit button nothing will happen.
Anyone can help?
Thank you very much in advance

Comment: your PHP code is all commented...! And may be not calling AjaxJson() function...!

Comment: You never call `AjaxJSON()` ?

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

```
$("#loginForm").click(function() {
    var jsonlogin=new Object();
    jsonlogin.username=$('#username').val();
    jsonlogin.password=$('#password').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'login.php',
        async: false,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: jsonlogin,
        success:function(response){
            if (response['result']=="login successful")
            {
                change();
            }
        }
    });
})
```

**EDITED CODE**

you have not implemented DOM ready method correctly

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // code goes here
    });
```

Comment: Oops...I didn't notice I was using 'data' as the response variable XD
Thank you!
Despite this, the script still doesn't show up...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because all the php is commented out?

Also in your success function should look like this:

```
success: function(response){
    dosomethingwithrespones(response);
}
```

The data in the $.ajax denotes what you send.

Comment: Ehm, ignore the comments, the original code isn't commented, that's because of some debug trials XD
Ok, I'll try editing the success function

Answer (score 0):

why are you using **function ajaxJson()**... try to remove it and if you really want to use it then modify your button code like this and remove `$("#loginForm").click(function() { }` from jquery...

```
  <input type="submit" id="loginForm" class="button positive" onclick="ajaxJson()">
```

and change `<script type="text/javascript">` instead of `<script language="javascript">`.. this identifier is not standard, this attribute has been deprecated(outdated by newer constructs) in favor of type.

**first way**

```
 function ajaxJson()
 {
       //your code goes here without triggering **click** event.. 
 }

 <input type="submit" id="loginForm" class="button positive" onclick="ajaxJson()">
```

**second way**

```
  $("#loginForm").click(function() 
  {
      //your code goes here...
  }

  <input type="submit" id="loginForm" class="button positive">
```

keep everything outside **$(document).ready** function...

hope it may help you

Comment: Thank you for your answer! :)
I tried the first way but it still won't work...Script doesn't load at all

Comment: have you kept your code outside $(document).ready() function? or else try, keep your javascript code after html

Comment: I tried now and it didn't help :( what do you mean with "keeping my javascript code after html?" By the way I'm wondering if there's a problem with the PHP script, but that would be very strange as I can't run it even if I just echo the "login successful" string without doing anything else...

Comment: try to change <script type="text/javascript"> bcz i think language="javascript" is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

try this query in login.php,

```
     $str="SELECT ID FROM users WHERE username='".$result->username."' AND password='".$result->password."' ";
```

Jquery:

```
           $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#loginForm").click(function() {
                var jsonlogin=new Object();
                jsonlogin.username=$('#username').val();
                jsonlogin.password=$('#password').val();
                var sendstr = JSON.stringify(jsonlogin);
                $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'login.php',
                        async: false,                         
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: sendstr,
                        success:function(response){
                        if (response.result=="login successful")
                            {
                             change();
                            }else{
                                alert(response.result);
                                return false;
                            }   
                        }
                    });

                 });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missed ending { and  } for ready function.try below code.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title> Login </title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript">
function change()
{
document.location.href="http://www.java2s.com";
}

$(document).ready(function () {
$("#loginForm").click(function() {
alert("hi");
var jsonlogin=new Object();
jsonlogin.username=$('#username').val();
jsonlogin.password=$('#password').val();
var sendstr = JSON.stringify(jsonlogin);
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'login.php',
        async: false,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: sendstr,
        success:function(response){
        if (response['result']=="login successful")
            {
            change();
            }
        }
    });

    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1> INSERT USERNAME AND PASSWORD</h1>
<input type="text" id="username" name="username"> USERNAME <br>
<input type="password" id="password" name="password"> PASSWORD <br>
<input type="button" id="loginForm" class="button positive">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply :)
It says hi! XD
It doesn't do anything else, but surely it's better than nothing!

Comment: I have added That Alert to check Execution or Enter point of Ajax call function.is it working now ?